# How to escape XSS from uploaded filename?

Tags: javascript, html, security, spring-boot, xss

I want to fix xss vulnerability.

Scenario - following:
1. I' ve created file with name `<imgsrc=x onerror=alert(document.cookie)>`
2.I have html input on my page and I try to load file created on step_1 and see:

[image]

Obviously malicious code from file name executes.

code:

```
<form id="uploadForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input class="custom-file-input" name="file" id="uploadFile" type="file" />
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="uploadFile">Choose CSV file...</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="" id="uploadSuccess">
                            <p class="text-success">Success!</p>
                            <p class="text-success" id="successText"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="" id="uploadError">
                            <p class="text-danger">Something has gone wrong!</p>
                            <p class="text-danger" id="errorText"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

js:

```
$("#uploadForm").off('submit').on('submit', (e) => {
        let url = "rest_upload";
        let form = $("#uploadForm")[0];
        let data = new FormData(form);

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
            .done((data) => {
                $('#uploadError').hide();
                $('#uploadSuccess').show();
                $('#successText').text(data);
            })
            .fail((err) => {
                if (err.status === 401) return;

                $('#uploadSuccess').hide();
                $('#uploadError').show();
                $('#errorText').text(err.responseText);
            });
    });
}
```

**How can I prevent it?**

Is it possible to prevent it on server side somehow?

Comment: The JS code doesn't appear to use the file name at all. It looks very much like a serverside problem indeed. Please post the code that handles the upload and generates the html.

Comment: @Bergi, looks like *$('#successText').text(data);* prints maliscious code

Comment: But that's fine, it should *print* the malicious code. It doesn't run it (like in your screenshot)?